# Rails - view a picture which represents data in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I'm searching for some idea how to let the stars view like on this example:

[image]

Right now, I have a table with a column for the black stars and a column for the grey stars.(in "Hüllenkontrolle" for example a "2" for 2 black stars and "4" for 4 grey stars). So I thought about something that shows another picture depending on which number is in the database (1 = 1 Star, 2 = 2 stars, 3 = 3 stars, 4 = 4 stars...)

I have no idea what to search on internet or how to realize that not the numbers will be viewed but some stars. Has anybody any idea how to implement this?

---

some information about my database model: http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/kwenevyz/beziehungen.png

- all data is viewed in the employee's html.erb.
- the black stars represent the current_qualification-table (column "qualificationstars"), the grey stars represent the expected qualification-table (column "qualificationstars").
  Right now it's written in html.erb like this:

`<% @employee.position.expected_qualifications.each do |expected_qualification| %> 
    <%= expected_qualification.qualificationstars %>
    <%end%>`

---

Some good news! This seems to work

```
<% @employee.position.skills.zip(@employee.position.expected_qualifications, @employee.current_qualifications).each do |skill, expected_qualification, current_qualification| %>
    <p>
    <% (current_qualification.istqualifikation).times do %>
            <%= image_tag("black.png") %>
    <% end %>
    <% (expected_qualification.sollqualifikation - current_qualification.istqualifikation).times do %>  
        <%= image_tag("grey.png") %>
    <% end %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This is how it looks in browser now:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an image file each for a black and grey star, try something like this in your view:

```
<% @employee.position.expected_qualifications.each do |expected_qualification| %>

<% @employee.current_qualification.qualificationstars.times do %>
<%= image_tag("black_star.png") %>
<% end %>

<% [expected_qualification.qualificationstars - @employee.current_qualification.qualificationstars].times do %>
<%= image_tag("grey_star.png")  %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

EDIT:

The images go into "public/images" (Rails < 3.1) or "app/assets/images" (Rails 3.1)

EDIT 2: Using your model names.

(I'd suggest renaming "qualificationstars" to simply "stars" in your DB. qualification.qualificationstars is redundant and a bit cumbersome.)

Comment: @ Thilo: Oh, wow, thanks for this input. Now other 2 questions: **QUESTION 1:** Where to put the picture of the black and grey star so rails will find it? In the same folder like my html.erb? 
**QUESTION 2:** okay, so @model is my table, right? I edited my first post with information about my model because it's quite more complex. Now I simply wanted to view the black stars in my example: `<% @employee.position.expected_qualifications.each do |expected_qualification| %> 
 <p> <%= expected_qualification.qualificationstars.times { image_tag("black_star.png") } %>
 <%end%>`

Comment: at least there was no error, but it also didn't show any pictures- just the numbers.

Comment: BTW, @model in not your table. It's a placeholder for the instance of your class that has the stars attribute since I didn't know your class names. So in your case, @employee.position.expected_qualification and @employee.current_qualification, respectively.

Comment: My bad. Fixed the blocks, try this version. If somebody knows a one line version of the 3 line blocks, please chime in.

Comment: thanks alot for your effort! 
Yes, I think I'll rename "qualificationstars" into "stars" next time, you're right. I implemented your code and it's so logical (for me), but rails gives me a `noMethodError`: undefined method `current_qualification' for #<Employee:0x2e3e5b8>. So it seems it has some problems with the times-loop?

Comment: Do you have :has_one current_qualification in your Employee model? Or is it a :has_many? Then you need to select the qualification you want to compare, e.g. @employee.current_qualifications.first, or loop through all of them. If neither works, post the relevant sections of your models.

Comment: It's a :has_many association (as you can see in the picture), because both tables are additionally a join table.  For example the **expected_qualification table** is a join table between position and skills: a position has many skills and a skill belongs to many positions. Same for the **current_qualification table**: An employee has many skills and a skill has many employees.

Comment: Good news! with a little bit modification, it seems like it's working now. I edited my first post.

Comment: One line version could be something like `<%= raw image_tag("black_star.png") * @employee.current_qualification.qualificationstars %>` since you can multiply a string by a number x to repeat it x times, no?